# VSTO C# Word Template Publishing No Installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsto

I'm a newbie here and a newbie in VSTO.

I've created a VSTO Word Template using C# and I want to get the final template file (with code functions) to give to my boss without installing anything.

Is this even possibly? If yes... HOW?

Hope you guys could help me!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. If you want to move files without installing anything, you need to develop a VBA macro and save the Word file using the macro enabled file format. In case of document-level add-ins you need to create an installer:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)